# Not able to get action event on button click in push notification in apple watch device

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

**Working on apple watch notification integration :**:- i m not able to get action event of button click in push notification.

**//IOS code**

**1.make function in AppDelegate file for integration custom push notification.**

```
func registerSettingsAndCategories() {

    let categories = NSMutableSet()
    let acceptAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    acceptAction.title = "View"
    acceptAction.identifier = "view"
    acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    acceptAction.authenticationRequired = false

    let inviteCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    inviteCategory.setActions([acceptAction],forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    inviteCategory.identifier = "myCategory"

    categories.addObject(inviteCategory)
    // Configure other actions and categories and add them to the set...

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound],categories: (NSSet(array: [inviteCategory])) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
```

**2.in AppDelegate file delegate method for handle notification:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {
   print("handleActionWithIdentifier Appdel : \(userInfo)   \(identifier)")
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

**3.In NotificationController file handle notification method in Watchkit Extension target :**

```
override func handleActionWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    print("handleActionWithIdentifier \(remoteNotification)")
    if identifier == "myCategory"{
    }
}
```

i know that if i will click on "view" button then handleActionWithIdentifier method should be called but in my case handleActionWithIdentifier method is not called.i m stucked in this issue for last 2 days.
so anyone can help me for resolving this issue?

Comment: Did you try to look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160398/apple-watch-watchkit-push-action

Comment: ya but i want to get button action event on push notification's alert.